# Android studio project App/Tests

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I created and empty Android studio proect, and it created an app/tests module that exists along side the app/java module. How do I safely remove this?

Right clicking and selecting refactor presents me with a disabled delete option.

And my app/build.gradle also references it.

Comment: Why do you want to remove it, are you not going to test your app?

Comment: That is insignificant.